# I'm trying to start selenium but it is showing this error i am thinking this is related to chrome driver exe or version mismatch plzz clarify

Tags: java, exception, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5foo0.png)

i wrote code like this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
> to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
> system property; for more information, see
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
> version can be downloaded from
> http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html     at
> com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
> at Selenium.Open_browser.main(Open_browser.java:14)

Comment: don't post images, post the actual code

Answer (score 0):

Driver path should be set before browser launch as given below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```